# Send On Behalf Of - Nodejs Example

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to use the SOBO feature of docusign, and I'm using the Nodejs api wrapper.  I have been unable to find any examples, or mention, of SOBO using nodejs.  How would I go about this?

https://github.com/docusign/docusign-node-client

Answer (score 0):

You need to add SendOnBehalfOf filed to the X-DocuSign-Authentication header. Using Node API wrapper, your code will look like this:

```
var SendOnBehalfOf = 'mr-ceo@example.com';
var creds = JSON.stringify({
  Username: email,
  Password: password,
  IntegratorKey: integratorKey,
  SendOnBehalfOf: SendOnBehalfOf
});
```

Comment: More about SOBO using REST API: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/sobo.html